# File upload with flow.js server get response 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ng-flow

im using flow.js to upload files to the server, at the moment i am uploading just a single file and check on my upload route if i get the file i send.

So in the angular side i have somehing like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>flow image example</h1>
  <hr class="soften"/>

  <div>
    <div class="thumbnail" ng-hide="$flow.files.length">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail" ng-show="$flow.files.length">
      <img flow-img="$flow.files[0]" />
    </div>
    <div>
     <span class="btn btn-primary" ng-hide="$flow.files.length" flow-btn flow-attrs="{accept:'image/*'}">Select image</span>
      <span class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="$flow.files.length" flow-btn flow-attrs="{accept:'image/*'}">Change</span>
      <span class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="$flow.files.length"
         ng-click="$flow.cancel()">
        Remove
      </span>
    </div>
    <p>
      Only PNG,GIF,JPG files allowed.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**i injected the ng-flow module without problems and then in my angular controller side i use the app.config like this:**

```
app.config(['flowFactoryProvider', function (flowFactoryProvider) {
  flowFactoryProvider.defaults = {
    target: 'http://localhost:8080/upload',
    permanentErrors: [404, 500, 501],
    maxChunkRetries: 1,
    chunkRetryInterval: 5000,
    simultaneousUploads: 4
  };
  flowFactoryProvider.on('catchAll', function (event) {
    console.log('catchAll', arguments);
  });
  // Can be used with different implementations of Flow.js
  // flowFactoryProvider.factory = fustyFlowFactory;
}]);
```

it feels that this side is working atleast, because i get a error from the server side, this is the error i get:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/upload?flowChunkNumber=1&flowChunkSize=1048576&flowCu…-1692jpg&flowFilename=1692.jpg&flowRelativePath=1692.jpg&flowTotalChunks=1 404 (Not Found)
```

and finally i got this in my router

```
router.post('/upload',multipartMiddleware ,function (req, res) {
  flow.post(req, function(status, filename, original_filename, identifier) {
    console.log('POST', status, original_filename, identifier);
    if (ACCESS_CONTROLL_ALLOW_ORIGIN) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }
    res.status(status).send();
  });
});
```

if someone can give me a tipe why it fail i appreciate a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

Seem to be making GET request to POST endpoint.

Comment: exactly, you are right the api doesn't say how to send the post, i will investigate

Comment: i keep getting flow.get is not a function you know why?

Comment: No idea as of now.

Comment: flow-init="{testChunks:false}"  use this